# Filtering results in an excel graph

Tags: excel, graph, spreadsheet

I am trying to do a task in Excel, where I have a table with columns of data, and they then get displayed on the graph below. What I want to happen is to be able to select which columns I want to be displayed on the graph, for example, I only want 3 of the 6 columns displayed on the graph, how would I do this?

https://gyazo.com/265ea7a397d4defa6260462e0e9ec335
https://gyazo.com/160b332e39be2b46a1cfcc1c1ec5ff5c

Above are images off the spreadsheet. The graph shows the 'Landing arm' and the 'Take off arm' along with the weight(kg) and I need to find a way to make only the sectors I select be shown onto the graph.

Comment: Can you provide any sample data and example(s) of what your desired outcome is/are? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to duplicate your data using an IF statement to include a condition to display either the data or NA(). Then plot the duplicated data using the condition to control whether or not the data is displayed.

For example, assuming for Sector 1:

- F18: take-off kg
- G19: take-off arm
- F20: landing Kg
- G21: landing Arm

Use a dedicate line to input whether you want a sector to display, say line 24. So for Sector 1 use cell G24.

Then create a duplicate set of data using formulas:

`=IF(G24="Y",F18,NA())`

`=IF(G24="Y",G19,NA())`

`=IF(G24="Y",F20,NA())`

`=IF(G24="Y",F21,NA())`

You now have 4 field that will display the original values if G24 has "Y" in it, and will display #N/A errors if G24 doesn't have a Y in it.

Do this for every Sector (with each sector having it's own single Y/N field for controlling whether values or errors are displayed).

You plot your chart using these new calculated values. Values of #N/A don't get ignored and aren't plotted.

You can then control which Sectors are displayed in the chart by changing the Y/N field for each sector.